# Canvas2Image Downloads Image to Folder in Server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html2canvas

So I am using very simple Html2Canvas and Canvas2Image code. The finished product will be a generating poster using PHP randomly loading elements, so therefore the div needs to be converted to an image to be saved/printed. (I've striped the code down here to the very very basics).

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(function() { 
   $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($(".widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
          }
      });
   });
}); 
 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="widget">
 text
</div><br/>

<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save Image"/>
<div id="img-out"></div>
```

CSS

```
.widget {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: white;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 5px solid black;
  }
```

All very simple. But I want the image output on button click, as well as being displayed on the page, to be **downloaded to the user's computer** and to a **folder in my server using PHP or AJAX with a random file name**. I'm sure the downloading to the user's computer is quite simple, and the saving to my server is more complicated.

[JSFIDDLE OF CURRENT CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/kzk9gu1b/)

This is the randomly loading generator that I have to use this with, just for reference: [click here](http://freeposterdesigner.com/mock2.php).

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of the same ?

Comment: Yes, http://jsfiddle.net/kzk9gu1b/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the links to Canvas2Image and use an ajax request to send the image to server. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/kzk9gu1b/1/) is the link to the fiddle.

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                var image = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas);
               var image_data = $(image).attr('src');
              //make an ajax call here sending image_data to the server
              /*
              $.ajax({
              url: 'localhost:3000/save_image',
              data:{ image: image_data},
              success: function(){

              }
              });
              */
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is anyone able to point me in the right direction for giving this download a .png file extension.  This is the script I am working on here - http://tupplefly.com.au/apps/vape_calculator/